# Time, C and PHP

Tags: php, c, arduino

I have a PHP website that I want to interface with Arduino. What would be the best way to keep track of time in both, for example if my PHP page displays current time, say 9 p.m., and I have a dropdown, labeled "Next activate", which will activate something at time X, say 11 p.m.

How would I accomplish this? How could I tell Arduino, which is programmed in C, to activate at time 11 p.m. when right now it is 9 p.m.?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do (assuming a Unix system) is to have the Arduino listen for a signal over the serial port, and write a little application that pokes it when you want it to update.  Then just use the Unix `at` utility to trigger the event.

Another approach would be to use an asynchronous job dispatch daemon, such as [Beanstalk](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/), which would allow you to have a persistent service talking to the Arduino and have transient web requests queueing jobs to manipulate it.